# Would this sentence be incorrect If we omit the definite articles?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

> Bridge relays (or "bridges" for short) are Tor relays that aren't
>   listed in the main Tor directory. Since there is no complete public
>   list of them, even if your ISP is filtering connections to all ***the***
>   known Tor relays, they probably won't be able to block all ***the***
>   bridges. If you suspect your access to the Tor network is being
>   blocked, you may want to use bridges.

If we omit the definite articles in bold would the sentence still be correct?

Comment: You are talking about specific relays and bridges, not relays and bridges in general. So you cannot omit "the".

Comment: It might sound better to you if you use "all *of* the".

Comment: Did you find this sentence somewhere or did you write it yourself? If the former, please edit your question and add a link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences would still be correct if you removed the words in bold. Indeed, the first instance of '**the**' being removed would make its sentence sound better.

However, the second time '**the**' is used, it clarifies the meaning of the sentence. Without it, the sentence implies that every bridge in the world will be blocked, but that clearly not the case.

In this context, the second '**the**' sentence is preferable with it in, but the sentence would still be correct without it.

Feel free to ask further questions about my answer in the comment section.

Comment: I disagree about the first **the**. The text speaks about *some known relays* and **of** after **all** would also be pleasant.